# VBA Macro Runtime Error # 13, can you help me find issue in code?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm in the process of converting a macro for excel to be able to export our inventory from our point of sales and import to our new eCommerce platform. The last part of my macro is tricking me (since I am not a pro at VBA), I need to cross reference one column to determine the value of a cell in that column and then change the value another cell in another column (in the same row). So, it's a standard if statement. Here is an example of the code.

```
 If Range("F2:F" & Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row).Value = "AMP" And Range("G2:G" & Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row).Value = "10" Then
                Range("G2:G" & Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row).Replace What:="10", Replacement:="Acoustic Guitar"
            End If
```

So, a `runtime error #13` indicates a variable or property isn't of the correct type. Can someone help me indicated the non-corrected variable or property? This initially worked for me but has now been giving me this error. Thank you for your time and may you have a great day! -Paul

Answer (score 0):

Your `IF` statement is testing a **multi-cell** range against a **single** value, and that will fail.  So will this:

```
Sub dural()
    If Range("F2:F100").Value = "X" Then
        MsgBox "X"
    Else
        MsgBox "Y"
    End If
End Sub
```

[image]

If you want to find which cell in column **F** has the value *AMP*, then yo should use the *FIND()* statement.